# Flink SQL OPTIONS for 'streaming'='true' doesn't work with JOIN

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, apache-iceberg

I'm writing a Flink job that will read from Iceberg, perform a join and then write to another Iceberg table. The SQL that I have works, but only runs once and then finishes. Reading the documentation I can configure it to run continuously, and react on new Iceberg snapshots, by adding this SQL comment: `/*+ OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='10s', 'starting-strategy'='YOUR_STARTING_STRATEGY_HERE') */`

[Documentation link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/hive/hive_read_write/)
Documentation example:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM hive_table 
/*+ OPTIONS('streaming-source.enable'='true', 'streaming-source.consume-start-offset'='2020-05-20') */;
```

[Looking at Iceberg flink documentation I found this](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/flink-queries/#flink-streaming-read)

```sql
SELECT * FROM sample /*+ OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='1s')*/ ;
```

With this example in mind, I wrote the following which doesnt work:

```sql
INSERT INTO lake.gold_feedback_answers
SELECT
  a.`answer_id` AS `answer_id`,
  a.`answer_set_id` AS `answer_set_id`,
  a.`question_item_id` AS `question_item_id`,
  a.`answer` AS `answer`,
  a.`created` AS `answer_created`,
  aset.`created` AS `answerset_created`,
  aset.`respondant_id` AS `respondant_id`,
  aset.`completed` AS `answerset_completed`,
  s.`survey_id` AS `survey_id`,
  s.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,
  s.`survey_start` AS `survey_start`,
  s.`survey_end` AS `survey_end`,
  s.`survey_language` AS `survey_language`,
  s.`archived` AS `survey_archived`
FROM
  lake.silver_filter_dbo_answers a
JOIN
  lake.silver_filter_dbo_answersets aset ON a.`answer_set_id` = aset.`answer_set_id`
JOIN
  lake.silver_filter_dbo_survey s ON aset.`survey_id` = s.`survey_id`
WHERE
  a.`op` = 'c'
  AND aset.`op` = 'c'
/*+ OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='10s', 'starting-strategy'='INCREMENTAL_FROM_LATEST_SNAPSHOT') */;
```

Exception is:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "/*+" at line 26, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "EXCEPT" ...
    ....
```

However, using it in simpler cases works:
Example 1:

```sql
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable
  SELECT
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.RowID') AS row_id,
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.SetId') AS set_id, 
      created, 
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Op') AS op, 
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Deleted') AS deleted 
    FROM mydb.sometable
    /*+  OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='10s')  */
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Op') = 'c' OR JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Op') IS NULL ;
```

Example 2:

```sql
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable
  SELECT
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.RowID') AS row_id,
      JSON_VALUE(data, '$.SetId') AS set_id, 
    FROM mydb.sometable
    /*+  OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='10s')  */;
```

I also tried configuring this directly in the environment and running the vanilla versions of SQL. But that didn't continuously run the SQL, just once and finish.

```java
tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("pipeline.monitor-interval", "10s");
tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("pipeline. Streaming", "true");
tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("pipeline.streaming.enable", "true");
tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("streaming-source.enable", "true");
tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("streaming", "true");
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried placing the comment at different parts of join queryies and searching the documentation, but the link and example I pasted seems to be the only reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comment needs to come immediately after the table name. An alternative is to specify the option in the `CREATE TABLE` DDL, as shown in the example in [this section](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/table/hive/hive_read_write/#temporal-join-the-latest-partition) of the docs, e.g.,

```sql
SET table.sql-dialect=hive;
CREATE TABLE dimension_table (
  product_id STRING,
  update_user STRING,
  ...
) PARTITIONED BY (pt_year STRING, pt_month STRING, pt_day STRING) TBLPROPERTIES (
  'streaming-source.enable' = 'true',
   ...
);
```

Comment: This seems right. Using `lake.silver_filter_dbo_survey s ON aset.'survey_id ...` caused the error but placing the comment between the table name and the alias made it work: `lake.silver_filter_dbo_survey /*+  OPTIONS(..).. s ON aset.'survey_id. ..`. I also noticed I had to palce this comment behind all the FROM and JOIN statement, and not behind the INSERT statement, otherwise the INSERT would stream, but the JOINS/WHEREs would run once and finish. Further more, I also see that there was duplicate data after an initial data stream, which I corrected using v2 tables and upsert. Thanks